# Are we ready to reopen this question?

Tags: discussion

I edited [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363316/can-functional-programming-used-for-solving-problems-which-require-randomness) to make it different from the former duplicate one it links to. Can we reopen it now, or do you still think it looks like a dupe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a good edit with a specific question that is fundamentally different from the related question.

I reopened the question to give it another chance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and for reopening.